# Change style of first page of article

Tags: header-footer, article

I'm trying to add a footer to the first page of my article, but I can't find a way to change its style.

I've tried writing at the top before everything:

```
\begin{document}

\fancypagestyle{firststyle}
{
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyfoot[R]{\footnotesize Page \thepage}
}

% first page
\pagestyle{firststyle}

...
```

But it still keeps the plain style. Setting the style for the whole document worked on every page except the first.

Apparently the `article` class always overwrites any style of the first page to plain. How can I change this behaviour?

Comment: Do you happen to have a `\maketitle` in there somewhere? If so put `\thispagestyle{firstpage}` just after your `\maketitle`.

Comment: (Part of `\maketitle` is the command `\thispagestyle{plain}`, so you have to undo that change if you call `\maketitle`.)